# Tengo un bucle infinito en mi progama Java Threads

Tags: java

Primeramente os explico de que va mi progama . El progama es un progama en Java en Threads , que simula el MonkeyPoppers y cuando genero todos los monos empieza hacer un bucle infinito sin parar Y no logro identificar donde esta el error

Os paso el codigo de todo el progama , Tengo 3 clases de los cuales ellos son Threads que funcionan a la vez para poder hacer el progama . Me podeis ayudar porfa

Saludos

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numVidas;
        int numMonos;
        int intervaloRecarga;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            System.out.println("Introduce el numero de monos (3-10)");
            numMonos=sc.nextInt();
        }while(numMonos < 3 || numMonos>10);

        do{
            System.out.println("Introduce el intervalo de Recarga (400-2000 milis)");
            intervaloRecarga=sc.nextInt();
        }while(intervaloRecarga < 400 || intervaloRecarga>2000);

        do{
            System.out.println("Introduce el numero de vidas (15-20)");
            numVidas=sc.nextInt();
        }while(numVidas < 3 || numVidas>20);


        GeneradorGlobo generadorGlobo = new GeneradorGlobo();
        Bomba bomba = new Bomba(generadorGlobo);
        Mono[] monos = new Mono[numMonos];
        for (int i = 0; i < numMonos; i++) {
            monos[i] = new Mono(i + 1, intervaloRecarga, numVidas, generadorGlobo);
            monos[i].start();
        }
        bomba.start();
    }
}
public class GeneradorGlobo extends Thread{

    private int numGlobos = 0;

    public int generarGlobo() {
        int numGlobosGenerados = (int) (Math.random() * (50 - 35 + 1)) + 35;
        numGlobos += numGlobosGenerados;
        System.out.println("Generados " + numGlobosGenerados + " globos. Total de globos: " + numGlobos);
        return numGlobosGenerados;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (numGlobos < 200) {
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            generarGlobo();
        }
    }

    public int getNumGlobos() {
        return numGlobos;
    }
    public synchronized boolean popGlobo() {
        if (numGlobos > 0) {
            numGlobos--;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}

public class Bomba extends Thread{

    private GeneradorGlobo generadorGlobo;

    public Bomba(GeneradorGlobo generadorGlobo) {
        this.generadorGlobo = generadorGlobo;
    }

    public void explotar() {
        int numGlobosExplotados = 50;
        int numGlobosRestantes = generadorGlobo.generarGlobo() - numGlobosExplotados;
        if (numGlobosRestantes < 0) {
            numGlobosRestantes = 0;
        }
        System.out.println("Explotada la bomba. Globos restantes: " + numGlobosRestantes);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (generadorGlobo.getNumGlobos() < 200) {
            try {
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            explotar();
        }
    }
}

public class Mono extends Thread {

    private int id;
    private int recargaPistola;
    private int numVidas;
    private int pistolasCargadas;
    private GeneradorGlobo generadorGlobo;
    private boolean seguirAtacando;

    public Mono(int id, int recargaPistola, int numVidas, GeneradorGlobo generadorGlobo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.recargaPistola = recargaPistola;
        this.numVidas = numVidas;
        this.generadorGlobo = generadorGlobo;
        this.pistolasCargadas = 3;
        this.seguirAtacando = true;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (seguirAtacando && numVidas > 0) {
            // Recargar pistola
            try {
                Thread.sleep(recargaPistola);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            pistolasCargadas = 3;

            // Atacar globos
            for (int i = 0; i < 5 && seguirAtacando && numVidas > 0; i++) {
                if (pistolasCargadas > 0) {
                    pistolasCargadas--;
                    if (generadorGlobo.popGlobo()) {
                        System.out.println("Mono " + id + " ha explotado un globo!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Mono " + id + " se ha retirado.");
    }

    public void detener() {
        seguirAtacando = false;
    }

    public int getNumVidas() {
        return numVidas;
    }

    public void restarVida() {
        numVidas--;
        if (numVidas == 0) {
            System.out.println("Mono " + id + " ha perdido todas sus vidas.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: El generador de globos es un objeto compartido por todos los hilos del mono. Eso quiere decir que se le va a llamar simultáneamente para generar y destruir globos. Para garantizar un estado consistente creo que deberias incorporar algunos modificadores ```synchronized``` en el codigo de los generadores

Comment: El programa no termina abruptamente??? Creo que te faltan uno o varios ```thread.join()``` para que el hilo principal espere a que termine la simulacion

Comment: En el synchronized lo he puesto en la clase generadorglobos en el popGlobo

Comment: Hola Josep, una pregunta, se supone que es un auto-juego?, osea que la maquina juega sola, a partir de los valores que le da el usuario?.

Answer (score 1):

En la condición del bucle, la verificación es incorrecta, ya que se compara `numVidas < 3` en lugar de `numVidas < 15`. Esto causa un bucle infinito si se ingresa un número de vidas válido, pero menor a 15.

Para solucionar esto, en el bucle do-while correspondiente a la entrada de `numVidas`, se debe cambiar la condición para que verifique que numVidas esté entre 15 y 20:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Introduce el numero de vidas (15-20)");
    numVidas = sc.nextInt();
} while (numVidas < 15 || numVidas > 20);
```

Con esta corrección, el bucle infinito debería desaparecer y el programa debería funcionar correctamente.

Comment: Hola DevMind, te sugiero que edites tu respuesta, ya que no es correcta, la condición solo vuelve a pedir una entrada si se ingresa un valor menor que 3 o mayor que 20, si bien hay una inconsistencia entre el mensaje y lo que realmente ocurre en la verificación, eso no ocasiona un bucle infinito.